# Getting an 403 Forbidden error on submit

Tags: php, error-handling

I have just migrated a website online, and am currently testing it online, to make sure that it all works well.  On a couple of  particular page, when I submit, instead of submitting, I get a 403 forbidden error, which I had not seen in the localhost.  What might be the reason for them?

**error**

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /cms/CMShome.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Example of code giving me errors:

```
 if ($_POST) {
if (isset($_POST['homesavebtn'])){
$home_title = (isset($_POST['home_title']) ? $_POST['home_title'] : null);
$home_text = (isset($_POST['home_text']) ? $_POST['home_text'] : null); 
include 'connect.php';
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO content(name, fieldcontent) 
                      VALUES ('home_title', ?), ('home_text', ?)
                      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fieldcontent = VALUES(fieldcontent)");

    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $home_title, $home_text);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $conn->close();
    
}
```

}

code which is not giving me errors:

```
if ($_POST) {
else if(isset($_POST['update_contact'])) {
    $contact_title = (isset($_POST['contact_title']) ? $_POST['contact_title'] : null);
    $contact_email = (isset($_POST['contact_email']) ? $_POST['contact_email'] : null);
    $contact_para1 = (isset($_POST['contact_para1']) ? $_POST['contact_para1'] : null);
    $contact_para2 = (isset($_POST['contact_para2']) ? $_POST['contact_para2'] : null);
    $address = (isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : null);
    $contact_sub = (isset($_POST['contact_sub']) ? $_POST['contact_sub'] : null);                             
    
    include 'connect.php';
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO content(name, fieldcontent) VALUES ('contact_title', ?), ('contact_email', ?), ('contact_para1', ?), ('contact_para2', ?), ('address', ?), ('contact_sub', ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fieldcontent = VALUES(fieldcontent)");
    
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $contact_title, $contact_email, $contact_para1, $contact_para2, $address, $contact_sub);
    $stmt->execute();
    $conn->close();
}
}
```

Comment: What type of server are you using? Check your file's permissions and check your .htaccess that might be blocking your access if you're using an apache server

Comment: I'm using a shared hosting server (apache).   The thing is that only this piece of code is not working on the site (and another very simialr to it).

Comment: nothing to do with code or mysql this is purely a permission problem as @RalphMelhem as already pointed out. Check the server error logs for additional information.

Comment: I have serious doubts about that, since the rest of the code works, so I don't think it is a permission problem.

Comment: getting same problem. @e4c5 did you solved your problem?